# Convert number to date and time

Tags: python, date, time

I have time series with progressive number (first day is 1/1/1900) with decimals digits which are the time of the day. I need to convert them to date and time.

For example `42370.520833` should be `1/1/2016 12:30:00`.

Comment: any code of your progress so far?

Comment: What is `42370`? Days since first day? How did you calculate `1/1/2016 12:30`.

Comment: a progressive number can represent everything and nothing. Its essential information for the solution of this problem.

Comment: I assumed the number to be the number of days from `1900-01-01` and the answer I got was `2016-01-03 12:29:59.971200`. The number of days between `1900-01-01` and `2016-01-01` is `42368`. Perhaps its just a miscalculation?

Comment: @Kendas yup I got the same result, that's why I was asking that to OP.

Comment: Thank you everybody for your answers. Yes, there could be a miscalculation. I just converted it with the automatic converter in excel (by changing the cell format) and it gave me that result.

Answer (score 1):

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, time

base_ordinal = date(1900, 1, 1).toordinal()
days = 42370.520833
date = date.fromordinal(int(days) + base_ordinal)
fraction = days - int(days)
h = int(fraction * 24)
m = int((fraction*24 - h) * 60)
s = int((fraction*24*60 - h*60 -m) * 60)
t = time(h, m, s)

dtime = datetime.combine(date, t)
formatted = dtime.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
print(formatted)  # 03/01/2016 12:29:59
```

@kendas comment is true, there's a miscalculation.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sahmi, I used this method and it works fine!

Comment: Glad to help.  –